# What is good way to backtrack a function in your Android app (like a button) to the code that implements it?

Tags: android

I have a project that I did not develop but am trying to fix bugs in. There's a button that I press and then a bug occurs. I want to find out where in the code this button is implemented but its hard to trace it since there are so many classes and layout files. Usually, if there's text associated with the button, then I find the string in my strings.xml file and work my way back. Unfortunately, this button doesn't have any text associated with it.

Comment: Why don't you find it by its ID?

Comment: i guess you are new on android, if the button has an ID, find it in the .java file linked to this layout file. If it has no ID it must have an "onclick" inplementation, still located in the .java file of this xml.

Comment: if by bug you mean that the app crashes, you can simply see what happens in the stacktrace.

Comment: can you share your code and logcat, so that we can find out

Comment: @njzk2 Its not so much a bug as a possible feature implementation. In short, when this button is pressed, it starts a media player to play the file. Its also supposed to suspend any in-app downloads to free up the cpu while playing the media. However, its not doing the latter which could mean that it might not have been implemented at all or there's something else causing it to not stop.

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley Don't know the id to the button and haven't been able to locate the layout file that holds the button yet.

Comment: post stacktrace and the logcat

Comment: you can use the hierarchy viewer to find the information on the button, such as the id. You can also try to find the activity or the fragment in which the button is, by identifying other elements, like texts.

Comment: Thanks guys, I was able to find the button after some time spent searching, was just hoping there was a quick way that perhaps more experienced Android devs knew off. Doesn't look like there's a straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

Hey just connect your actual android phone and run the app on it and also open logcat, when you will click that button logcat should hopefully display all the errors and you can go to the function.
Try this and comment me back if it works

Comment: It's not an error so much as it's not doing a specific function. When the button is pressed, it starts the media file which is fine. It's also supposed to suspend background downloads that are happening within the app. It's not doing the latter.

Answer (score 0):

This is a unconvential method, but I used it in the beginning aswell. In Android Studio press `CTRL + H` to open the Find in Path dialog. This will search the whole project.

For a `Button` you might want to search e.g. `setOnClickListener`, `Button` etc. and navigate it down by this approach. This method will also find dynamically created Views in case it's not in the layout.xml